# Using plyr ldply parallel with function within function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I have a data frame with multiple IDs and I am trying to perform feature extraction on the different ID sets. The data looks like this:

```
    id  x    y 
1 3812 60    7
2 3812 63  105
3 3812 65 1000
4 3812 69    8
5 3812 75   88
6 3812 78   13
```

where id takes on about 200 different values. So I am trying to extract features from the (x,y) data, and I'd like to do it in parallel, since for some datasets, doing it sequentially can take about 20 minutes or so. Right now I am using dplyr as such:

```
x = d %>% group_by(id) %>% do(data.frame(getFeatures(., func_args))
```

where `func_args` are just additional function inputs to the function `getFeaures`. I am trying to use `plyr::ldply` with `parallel=TRUE` to do this, but there is a problem in that within `getFeatures`, I am using another function that I've written. So, when I try to run parallel, I get an error:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "desparsify""
In addition: Warning messages:
1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’
 
 Error in do.ply(i) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "desparsify""
```

where `desparsify` is a custom function written to process the (x,y) data (it effectively adds zeros to  x locations that are not present in the dataset). I get a similar error when I try to use the `cosine` function from package `lsa`. Is there a way to use parallel processing when calling external/non-base functions in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you set up **plyr** to parallelize, but I think I can guess what you're doing. I also guess you're on Windows.  Here's a teeny standalone example illustrating what's going on:

```
library(plyr)

## On Windows, doParallel::registerDoParallel(2) becomes:
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

desparsify <- function(x) sqrt(x)
y <- plyr::llply(1:3, function(x) desparsify(x), .parallel=TRUE)
## Error in do.ply(i) : 
##  task 1 failed - "could not find function "desparsify""
```

If you use **doFuture** instead of **doParallel**, the underlying future framework will make sure 'desparsify' is found, e.g.

```
library(plyr)

doFuture::registerDoFuture()
future::plan("multisession", workers = 2)

desparsify <- function(x) sqrt(x)
y <- plyr::llply(1:3, function(x) desparsify(x), .parallel=TRUE)
str(y)
## List of 3
##  $ : num 1
##  $ : num 1.41
##  $ : num 1.73
```

(disclaimer: I'm the author of the future framework)

PS. Note that **plyr** is a legacy package no longer maintained.  You might want to look into **future.apply**, **furrr**, or **foreach** with **doFuture** as alternatives for parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

There is. Take a look in the parApply functions family. I usually use the parLapply one.

You'll need to set the number of cores with `cl <- makeCluster(number of cores)`  and pass it, together with a vector of your ids (may depend on how your functions identify the entries for each id) and your functions, to parLapply to produce a list with the output of your function applied to each group in parallel.

```
cl <- makeCluster(number of cores)
ids=1:10               
clusterExport(cl=cl,varlist=c('variable name','function name')) ## in case you need to export variable/functions

result=parLapply(cl=cl,ids, your function)
stopCluster(cl)
```